# Is there any compile-time mechanism in Java to attempt to ensure that use of a particular class is always synchronized?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, concurrency, synchronization

We have a class in our codebase currently that uses the `synchronized` keyword at the method level to ensure data consistency in multithreaded operations.  It looks something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
   public synchronized void abc() { ... }

   public synchronized void def() { ... }

   //etc.
}
```

The nice thing about this is that anyone using the class gets the synchronization for free.  When you create an instance of `Foo`, you don't have to remember to access it inside of a `synchronized` block or anything like that.

Unfortunately, it seems that synchronization at the method level isn't going to cut it anymore.  Instead we're going to have to start synchronizing on `Foo` itself.  I don't think anything like `java.util.concurrent.AtomicReference` is going to cut it either.  I want to make sure no one else touches an instance of `Foo` while a particular (and possibly somewhat lengthy) operation is going on.  So now we're going to have blocks like this in the code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(); //this got created somewhere

//somewhere else entirely
synchronized(foo)
{
   //do operation on foo
   foo.doStuff();
   foo.doOtherStuff();
}
```

So the main thing I'm worried about is that a few developers and I share this code.  `Foo` objects are fairly ubiquitous.  Since we're not getting the synchronization for free any more at the method level, we must **ALWAYS** remember to access a `Foo` object within a `synchronized` block.

So my question is, is there any mechanism (built-in or third party) in Java to allow me to generate warnings or errors at compile-time if an instance of `Foo` is accessed outside of a `synchronized` block?

Ideally it would be something I can either do to the class declaration (made up example below):

```
@EnsureSynchronized
public class Foo
{
   //etc.
}
```

Or something I could do when I declare instances of `Foo` (made up example below):

```
@EnsureSynchronized
private Foo foo;
```

I know if I really wanted to I could probably write a custom FindBugs or PMD rule to do this, but I was hoping something like this already existed.

So I ask you, SO community, if you were in this situation, how would you try to ensure that `Foo` objects are only ever accessed and modified inside `synchronized` blocks?

Comment: Why are you worried you will need to do this?

Comment: It's not a requirement per se, but since all the developers agree that all use of these objects must be synchronized to avoid race conditions, it would be nice to have an automated way to enforce it.

Comment: @Kirk Agreed. For this scenario, the big problem with that is it's on a per call basis.  If I want to atomically call two methods, do some processing and call a third method, all without another thread interrupting, then method level synchronization isn't sufficient.

Comment: Even if there was a way to ensure that all references to foo is from  synchronized blocks/methods, if multiple synchronized methods are called in sequence from a non-synchronized method, your whole exercise would be in vain.

Comment: Considered if immutable objects would be feasible in your situation?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen More or less what's going on is that N threads are responsible for polling things for state and populating `Foo` objects with the results.  The other thread(s) are responsible for looking at `Foo` objects and making decisions based on the state held in them.  Not sure I have a good way to push that toward an immutable scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good at finding [inconsistent synchronization](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC) so as long as you have some code that synchronizes all accesses to an object, and run findbugs, it should alert you to failures to sync.

> A typical bug matching this bug pattern is forgetting to synchronize one of the methods in a class that is intended to be thread-safe.
>
> You can select the nodes labeled "Unsynchronized access" to show the code locations where the detector believed that a field was accessed without synchronization.
>
> Note that there are various sources of inaccuracy in this detector; for example, the detector cannot statically detect all situations in which a lock is held.  Also, even when the detector is accurate in distinguishing locked vs. unlocked accesses, the code in question may still be correct.

If that isn't sufficient, you can always annotate with [`net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe`](http://jcip.net/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/NotThreadSafe.html) which findbugs recognizes.

From [Chapter 10. Annotations](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html) :

> FindBugs also supports the following annotations:
>
> - ...
> - `net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe`

Comment: This looks quite promising.  I'll check it out and report back.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the check to be at compile time, FindBugs and PMD won't do. I would suggest Java's Annotation Processing Tool ([APT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html)). It will let you create a custom annotation processor that can add checks to the compilation process for uses of your annotated classes and cause compiler warnings or errors if your synchronization requirements are not met. In fact, you could even use it tamper with the code to add the synchronization during the compilation if it isn't already there.

To use the annotation processor you create, you just need to make sure it's on the classpath when you compile your project. No extra automated analysis needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `notify()` without a synchronized block around it or the method being synchronized you will get an `IllegalMonitorStateExcept` (see [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29)). However, doing it is very hacky and should, if at all, only be used for debugging and not in a production setting.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you may use [Thread.holdsLock()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock%28java.lang.Object%29).

Have you thought about inheriting from `Foo`, like `SynchronizedFoo` and using that in your code while others may still use `Foo` as needed?